# how to append data-icon after li menu

Tags: javascript, append

This Menu for example

```
          <ul class='sub-first menu'>
            <li class='iconify menu-item-type-label menu-item' data-icon=''><a href='javascript:void();' itemprop='url'>Menu 1.1</a></li>
            <li class='iconify menu-item-type-label menu-item' data-icon=''><a href='javascript:void();' itemprop='url'>Menu 1.2</a></li>
            
            <li class='iconify menu-item-type-label menu-item' data-icon='fa-support'><a href='javascript:void();' itemprop='url'>Menu 1.4</a></li>
            <li class='iconify menu-item-type-label menu-item' data-icon='fa-info'><a href='javascript:void();'> Menu 1.5</a></li>                   
          </ul>
```

I want This script below if i add on data-icon='fa-support'
then will be like this

```
<li class='iconify menu-item-type-label menu-item' data-icon='fa-support'><i class='fa fa-support'></i> <a href='javascript:;'>Menu 1.1</a></li>
```

Then this For the Script

```
var iconsArray = ['data-icon'];
$('.menu li').append(function(i) {
    return '<i class="fa ' + iconsArray[i] + '"></i>';
});
```

Sorry for bad english!
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

**Im assuming that elements in `iconsArray` is same as the number of `<li>`;**

```
var iconsArray = ['data-icon1', 'data-icon2','data-icon3','data-icon4'];
```

**Method 1**

```
  let i = 0;
  $('.menu li').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('data-icon', iconsArray[i]);
     i++;
  });
```

**Method 2**

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
iconsArray.forEach((val, index)=>{
  element[index].setAttribute('data-icon', val);
});
```